# AngularJS - Reset $scope.data to original values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nicktest2222/W4VaA/

I just want to be able to hit the reset button and put my original values back. Does anyone know the best way to go about doing this?

Thanks in advance

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
   {text:'learn angular', done:true},
   {text:'build an angular app', done:false}];

  $scope.orig = [$scope.data];

  $scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.data = $scope.orig;
  };

}
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

[The problem is in JS clone mechanics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085024/reset-a-model-with-angular-js). All you need to do is to create a deep copy of your model:

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = [
        {text:'learn angular', done:true},
        {text:'build an angular app', done:false}
    ];

    $scope.orig = angular.copy($scope.data);

    $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.data = angular.copy($scope.orig);
    };
}
```

[Here is the updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/W4VaA/1/)

Comment: My god....after 2.5 hours of headache, I found this brilliant solution.  I went to do it the dumb way: Find the index of the object that was modified from the array and get a copy of the original object.  This way is much shorter and sweeter!  Thank you so much

Comment: I tried similar way but it dint work in case of dropdowns, It was resetting the dropdown instead of going back to the ng-selected value, $route.reload() did the trick for me.

Comment: this saved my a$$

Answer (score 14):

The simplest option is to use [`angular.copy`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy) to clone the original data, and then again to reset the data in `$scope`.

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
    {text:'learn angular', done:true},
    {text:'build an angular app', done:false}
  ];

  var originalData = angular.copy($scope.data);
  $scope.reset = function() {
     angular.copy(originalData, $scope.data); 
  };
}
```

**Edit**: `angular.copy` when provided two values will empty the target object or array before copying the source values in to it.  This can be really useful when dealing with child scopes.

Comment: This is the only of the 3 answers that works when using 2 way binding. (for ex, on a modal dialog using resolve: { data : function () { return $scope.dataFromParentScope } }. I see what you mean by it being best when dealing with child scopes.

Comment: I tried similar way but it dint work in case of dropdowns, It was resetting the dropdown instead of going back to the ng-selected value, $route.reload() did the trick for me. It would be great if you can come up with a fiddle to prove it working for drop downs.

Answer (score 7):

madhead works initially, but afterwards the data is pointing to $scope.orig and reset would not work anymore. Would need to do a copy in the reset for it to work also.

Editted madhead's work:
http://jsfiddle.net/W4VaA/2/

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
    {text:'learn angular', done:true},
    {text:'build an angular app', done:false}
  ];

  $scope.orig = angular.copy($scope.data);

  $scope.reset = function() {
     $scope.data = angular.copy($scope.orig);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank God for new angular versions. but for those like me, that still have to maintain old angular js code you have to write some doggy code like this.

```
$scope.[moduleName] = { [variableName]: '' };

$scope.[formName].[variableName].$touched = false;
$scope.[formName].[variableName].$$untouched= false;
```

you can also write a function to handle lots of input elements like this. but it used jquery and bootstrap 3

HTML

```
<ng-form class="form" name="formName" novalidate>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">
                    input1 <span class="symbol required"></span>
                </label>
                <select id="input1" name="input1" class="form-control" required ng-model="model.input1">
                    <option value="">Select Optionn</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.Description}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-form>
```

Controller.js

```
$scope.resetForm = function () {
    $scope.model = { input1: '' }; // reset form value
        let form = $(".form"),
            frmElm = $scope.formName; // referees to name="" for ng-form element

        form.find('.form-control').each(function (item) {
            let element = $(this),
            id = element.attr("id");

        if (frmElm[id]) {
            var scopeElement = frmElm[id];
            scopeElement.$touched = false;
            scopeElement.$untouched = false;
        }
    })
};
```