# Reset form to initial values in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to reset a form to it's initial values in AngularJS?

I have a simple form with a field with `ng-model='my_object.my_value'`, which is disabled. When I start editing it, I copy `$scope.my_object` to `$scope.my_object_backup`.

If I click cancel, I disable the field and set `$scope.my_object = $scope.my_object_backup`. But the value I see in my input doesn't change.

Is there a way to got around this behavior?

I tried setting `value="{{my_object.my_value}}"` but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: how did you copy the object?

Comment: Basically the exact same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085024/reset-a-model-with-angular-js

Comment: I did a simple `$scope.my_object_backup = $scope.my_object`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [angular.copy](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy) to deep copy the object

```
$scope.my_object_backup = {};
angular.copy($scope.my_object, $scope.my_object_backup);
```

What you did `$scope.my_object_backup = $scope.my_object` is make reference assignment so they actually point to the exacly same object. So, if you modify via one reference, you will access to the modified object via the other reference.

Comment: Wow, I tried this first (like in the docs) but it always reset to null so I thought it was not good and went with `$scope.my_object_backup = $scope.my_object`... I tried again like you said, and noticed my `$scope.my_object_backup` was initialized with `null`... I changed it to `new Object()` and it works like a charm!