# AngularJS - Change the $scope object

Tags: javascript, object, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a very weird issue.

I have an object under the $scope

I using an angular.foreach loop but there is a problem.

when I'm trying to set a value depending on langKey(where langKey is 'en' or 'el') all the values are being updated by ingoring the langKey.

```
$scope.finalObject[langKey]['servicesElements'][itemKey]['name']  = something;
```

the problem still exists when I simply use the console in order to change the values from there.

I'm setting the value 'myCustomText' to the el version of the object

```
$scope.finalObject.el['servicesElements'][itemKey]['name'] = 'myCustomText'
```

BUT if i run this one

```
$scope.finalObject.en['servicesElements'][itemKey]['name']
```

it returns 'myCustomText' with no reason because what I changed was the el version not the en.

Is this normal? I'm totally stuck

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you create a Plunker script or something?

Comment: I'd recommend you check out the angular-translate module over at http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-translate. Also you'll need to post more code for your specific problem, it sounds like there's an issue with your loop somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well guys,

The problem was that I had declared the two different objects with the same source.

```
$scope.finalObject.el.servicesElements = something;
```

and

```
$scope.finalObject.en.servicesElements = something
```

I didn't have seen that before, but the browser was behaving like I have typed

```
$scope.finalObject.en.servicesElements = $scope.finalObject.el.servicesElements = something
```

and in every change of the one the other was following.

(in php is called pointer)

The solution was to use the angular's copy function

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy

So I simply used this SO answer [Reset a model with angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085024/reset-a-model-with-angular-js) did this

```
$scope.tmpVar = something;
$scope.finalObject.en.servicesElements = angular.copy($scope.tmpVar);
$scope.finalObject.el.servicesElements = angular.copy($scope.tmpVar);
```