# Clearing fields with angular?

Tags: angularjs

When the user clicks on a radio button I run:

```
$scope.clientClick = function() {

    //do stuff
}
```

I have a form, and I would like half of the fields on the form to be cleared in the above method.

I have done:

```
 $scope.clientClick = function() {

    $scope.entry.first_name = '';
    $scope.entry.last_name = '';
    $scope.entry.email = '';
    $scope.entry.tel = '';
    $scope.entry.gender = '';
    $scope.entry.job = '';
    $scope.entry.age = '';
}
```

But is there an easier way rather than listing each field again?

Comment: Cant you just clear $scope.entry?

Comment: @smk no, it clears the entire form, I only want part of it cleared.

Answer (score 0):

```
function initObject(obj) {
  for (var i in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      switch(typeof obj[i]){
        case 'string':
          obj[i] = '';
          break;
        case 'number':
          obj[i] = 0;
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Use this function. NEVER do this $scope.entry = {} or $scope.entry.name = null, it's safer and you won't get unnecessary errors when you have some parts of your code that expect a type. It's a lot easier just to set a string to "".

Answer (score 0):

I would use `$scope.entry = null` or `$scope.entry = {}`.

*Make code simple and readable.*

Comment: So as I know there is no way.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

```
['first_name', 'last_name', ...].forEach(function (f) {
    $scope.entry[f] = '';
});
```

## Long answer

In JavaScript, properties can be accessed in two ways:

```
obj.prop
obj['prop']
```

You can keep a list of strings with the properties that you want to clear, and then just iterate over it clearing each in turn.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that if you have a dependency to the radio button then the view model should reflect that it could be cleared:

```
$scope.entry.dependant = { first_name: '' ... }

$scope.clientClick = function() {

    $scope.entry.dependant = {};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have done some thing like [Reset a model with angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085024/reset-a-model-with-angular-js):

```
$scope.initial = [
  {
    first_name : '',
    last_name : '',
    email : '',
    tel : '',
    gender : '',
    job : '',
    age : ''
  }            
];
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wgR5c/3/)

```
$scope.clientClick = function() {
  angular.copy($scope.initial, $scope.entry);
});
```

Comment: This gives the error: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'push'

Comment: Fixed the error but this still does not work, it erases the entire form.

Comment: It should n't check the demo

Comment: Your demo does not reflect the question. It clears the entire set of data, I would like, for example in your demo, for last name to stay there when you click reset.