# How to reset form after submit in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and trying to do a project. I have a form which works perfectly. However, there is only one thing that I should do. After adding a customer, I need to clear the form. Because, when the user wants to add a second customer, tthe user sees the previously entered values.

```
$scope.add = function () {
        $scope.loading = true;
        $http.post('/api/Customer/', this.newcustomer).success(function (data) {
            alert("Added Successfully!!");
            $scope.addMode = false;
            $scope.customers.push(data);
            $scope.loading = false;

        }).error(function (data) {
            $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Adding Customer! " + data;
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
    };
```

Comment: Just set `this.newcustomer ={}`.

Comment: $scope.customer={};

Comment: @charlietfl, it didnt work

Comment: Show some relevant html for your `ng-model`s

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085024/reset-a-model-with-angular-js?

Comment: Please provide the HTML for this form.

Comment: the code from @charlietfl works like a sharm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$scope.add = function () {
        $scope.loading = true;
        $http.post('/api/Customer/', this.newcustomer).success(function (data) {
            alert("Added Successfully!!");
            $scope.addMode = false;
            $scope.customers.push(data);
            $scope.loading = false;
            this.newcustomer = {};

        }).error(function (data) {
            $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Adding Customer! " + data;
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
    };
```

Comment: `this` is not what you think it is. Different context in the callback

Answer (score -3):

You have to manually clear the values of the form elements

This should do it:

```
delete $scope.newcustomer
```